# Get the x and y data of an audio recording in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I print out the data (x,y) of a sound or a figure in python?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
rate, data = wav.read('90bpmsf.wav')
```

Comment: `plt.figure()`, `plt.plot(data)`, `plt.show()`

Comment: I don't need the plot, I need the real-time values in an excel file

Comment: @S. sami You should state your question clearly. What is exactly your desired output? state specific input and output, and state what you have tried to do to get that output.